# Gitlab CI Docker Network timeout

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've just set up Ubuntu Server 17.04 and installed Docker and Gitlab CI Runner. While it seems to work, any builds that require network access (e.g. npm, nuget etc.) the network traffic seems to take forever and ultimately times out.

This happens for both Internet and local address.

If I start a container manually and try to connect from that, it works perfectly. There's only an issue when the runner tries.

I find it odd that the git clone at the start of the build appears to work fine (local Gitlab server) because presumably that would need network access as well?

We have a proxy server for Internet access which I have configured but that should not be needed for local servers.

Comment: are you defining the http_proxy and https_proxy variables while doing the build?

Comment: Yes, they are set on the host and in the gitlab runner config.toml.

Comment: Start the exited container yourself by looking at `docker ps -a` and docker start <containerid> and see if you can debug?

Comment: I've been trying that. As far as I can tell, the environment variables are set currently but it just isn't using them. Even running `curl -v` the env var is being ignored. If I do `curl -v -x $HTTP_PROXY <url>` then it works fine. I can't figure why the env vars are being ignored.

Comment: Both the variable needs to be lower case and not upper case

Comment: Ahh ok. I've added both lowercase and uppercase now. That seems to have sorted curl. My nuget builds are working but my node builds are still horribly slow. I think that might be a different issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a whole series of problems.

1. The Docker IP addresses were conflicting with our local network - changed the Docker binding IP
2. Needed to use http_proxy rather than HTTP_PROXY
3. An npm package was cloning from git@github.com but our network blocks outbound SSH. Had to add `git config --global url.http://github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com`

Thanks for Tarun Lalwani for the help

Comment: Thanks for sharing the list of the issues you found. Glad to be of help